# Notes - searching

Tags: database, activity

How do I find a list of the notes I have added. I input a number of notes last week but neglected to grant permissions. how do I locate a list of those notes?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find all the users with Notes, you could use Advanced Search, expand the Notes section and enter '%' in the Notes text box (don't type in the quotes, just %)  % means 'match anything' but there must be a note there to match against.

If you want to limit that to those changed last week you can expand the Change Log section and set the Modified Between date to something suitable.  Note that this will give you those who have a Note and were modified last week - but it does not necessarily mean the Note was modified last week.

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach to Aidan's would be to use Search Builder for this. You hit the same issue that you will only pick up the date of the Contact record have some sort of modification made, but the benefit of Search Builder is you get to see the Note (Subject and/or Body) in the results table, eg the below (hmm though that seems to show that the Body actually didn't return the body and the Modified Date has slipped across one column. But hopefully it gives you the idea and that you can proceed without using the Body Only field

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have mysql access to the database, then in civicrm_note table you have the following columns so could use a sql query to get the required
[image]